# Using a Cursor inside a Stored Procedure to Write to a Table from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm struggling to write my first procedure to pull data from multiple tables together and write it to another table using a cursor to loop through all of the data.  Was hoping to find some help here.

I'm joining 6 tables back to the main table, Accounts, to displayed the required data. With the first cursor, I was joining five of the tables to get the needed information and then I wanted to add two more cursors to get phone numbers (primary and secondary) from a Phone Detail table added to the table.

Hopefully this makes sense. I'm sure I"m missing some thing in the SQL but basically I'd like to loop through the Accounts table and write the data into a new table and also loop through the Phone Detail table and get the primary phone for each account and then the secondary phone (while accounting for a NULL value) writing this to the new table as well.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CRM_Account_Info] 
    @AccountID int,
    @AccountName nvarchar(128),
    @Bus_Type nvarchar(50),
    @AccountAddr1 nvarchar(128),
    @AccountAddr2 nvarchar(128),
    @AccountCity nvarchar(32),
    @AccountState nvarchar(10),
    @AccountZip nvarchar(10),
    @Account_Coll_Area_CodeID int,
    @Account_Coll_Area nvarchar(50),
    @Account_CRC_ID int,
    @Account_CRC_Name nvarchar(100),
    @Account_Prime_Number nvarchar(120),
    @Account_2nd_Number nvarchar(120)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Truncate Accounts table 
    Execute Immediate 'Truncate DBO.CRM_Accounts';

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Grab Account ID, Account Name, Account Type, Address, City, State, Zip, Collection Area ID, Collection Area Description,
    -- Recruiter ID, Recruiter Full Name from the Accounts Table

    Declare Acct_Info cursor for
        Select 
           Acct.AccountID, Acct.Internalname, 
           QC.Descshort, 
           AD.Addr1, AD.Addr2, AD.City, AD.State, AD.Zip,
           Sub.CodeID, Sub.Description, 
           Peo.PersonID, Peo.Fullname
        from 
           Accounts as Acct
        inner join 
           AddressDetail AD on Acct.AccountID = AD.AccountID
        inner join 
           CenterDetail CD on Acct.Centerid = CD.CenterID
        inner join 
           People Peo on Acct.LeaderID = Peo.PersonID
        inner join 
           IDViewOrgSubCenter SUB on CD.OrgSubCenter = SUB.CodeID
        inner join 
           QuickCodes QC on Acct.AccountType = QC.CodeID

    Open Acct_Info -- Open cursor

    Fetch Next from Acct_Info into @AccountID, @AccountName, @Bus_Type, @AccountAddr1, 
                                   @AccountAddr2, @AccountCity, @AccountState, @AccountZip,
                                   @Account_Coll_Area_CodeID, @Account_Coll_Area, 
                                   @Account_CRC_ID, @Account_CRC_Name, @Account_Prime_Number, 
                                   @Account_2nd_Number

    Close Acct_Info  -- Close cursor

    -- Grab the Primary Phone for the Account
    Declare Primary_Phone cursor for

Select top 1 Acct.AccountID, PD.FormattedNumber
From PhoneDetail PD
inner join Accounts Acct on PD.AccountID=Acct.AccountID
Where PD.PrimaryPhone=1
And PD.AccountID=@AccountID

Close Primary_Phone  -- Close cursor

-- Grab the second phone for an account

Declare Secondary_Phone cursor for

Select top 1 Acct.AccountID, PD.FormattedNumber
From PhoneDetail PD
inner join Accounts Acct on PD.AccountID=Acct.AccountID
Where PD.PrimaryPhone<>1
And PD.AccountID=@AccountID

Close Secondary_Phone  -- Close cursor

-- Insert the values into the CRM table
Insert CRM_Accounts (
AccountID,
AccountName,
Bus_Type,
AccountAddr1,
AccountAddr2,
AccountCity,
AccountState,
AccountZip,
Account_Coll_Area_CodeID,
Account_Coll_Area,
Account_CRC_ID,
Account_CRC_Name,
Account_Prime_Number,
Account_2nd_Number
)
Values (
@AccountID,
@AccountName,
@Bus_Type,
@AccountAddr1,
@AccountAddr2,
@AccountCity,
@AccountState,
@AccountZip,
@Account_Coll_Area_CodeID,
@Account_Coll_Area,
@Account_CRC_ID,
@Account_CRC_Name,
@Account_Prime_Number,
@Account_2nd_Number
)
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you write a single select that gets all the data you need? If so then a simple `INSERT INTO`... `SELECT` would get you there without using cursors.

Comment: I've tried this, but I can't figure out how to write a single select when pulling multiple phone numbers from the same table.

Comment: so an account could have more than one phone number where primaryphone = 1? Can an account also have more than one phone number where primaryphone <>1? I assume this because you used `TOP 1`

Comment: You join onto a table twice. You will just need to alias it two different ways. I would join onto PhoneDetail two times: one where PrimaryPhone = 1 and another where PrimaryPhone <> 1.

Comment: Correct, an account could have multiple phone numbers and unfortunately, it can have more than one primary phone number (though it shouldn't). Unfortunately I found a case today where that happened and corrected it, but I want to make this fail safe in case it happened again.

Comment: To my best knowledge you have to declare variables inside the cursor.all the variables that you declared belong to the proc

Comment: @Michael I'm sure I'm missing something, but when I try to join the table twice I lose about 18.5k records.

Comment: @MISNole use a left join. I'm guessing a large number of accounts only have primary phone numbers (or no phone number!). Those records will not be returned if you use an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get it all in one query. I did 2 derived tables one of primary and one of secondary and gave them row numbers partitioned by accountid. Then in the join I only get the rownumber = 1 so that it only returns one number per accountid.

```
 SELECT Acct.accountid,
       Acct.internalname,
       QC.descshort,
       AD.addr1,
       AD.addr2,
       AD.city,
       AD.state,
       AD.zip,
       Sub.codeid,
       Sub.description,
       Peo.personid,
       Peo.fullname,
       pd1.formattedNumber,
       pd2.formattedNumber
FROM   accounts AS Acct
       INNER JOIN addressdetail AD
               ON Acct.accountid = AD.accountid
       INNER JOIN centerdetail CD
               ON Acct.centerid = CD.centerid
       INNER JOIN people Peo
               ON Acct.leaderid = Peo.personid
       INNER JOIN idvieworgsubcenter SUB
               ON CD.orgsubcenter = SUB.codeid
       INNER JOIN quickcodes QC
               ON Acct.accounttype = QC.codeid  
       LEFT JOIN (select accountid, formattednumber, primaryphone, row_number() over(partition by accountid order by formattednumber) as rNum  
                           from phonedetail where primaryphone = 1) pd1
                ON acct.accountid = pd1.accountid and pd1.rNum = 1
       LEFT JOIN (select accountid, formattednumber, primaryphone, row_number() over(partition by accountid order by formattednumber) as rNum  
                           from phonedetail where primaryphone <> 1) pd2
                ON acct.accountid = pd2.accountid and pd2.rNum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @JChao. Minor modificatino where I had to change the "and pd.rNum = 1 to pd1.rNum and the same for pd2.  But that does seem to be working nicely.

Comment: @MISNole sorry about that. I edited shortly after I posted it seeing the mistake.

Comment: No need to apologize, I had been trying to figure that out forever and I appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 0):

@JChao, I'm going to mark your answer correct as the SQL worked brilliantly but I'd like to post this here based on the recommendations received and for additional eyes to look over this procedure now.  It seems to work but I'd just like more experienced users to check it out to see if they spot any glaring mistakes:

The first step is to drop (or truncate) all data currently in the table and then write the select statement into my new table:

```
Create Procedure Update_CRM_Accts
--Alter Procedure Update_CRM_Accts
As
Begin
Truncate Table CRM_Accounts
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Insert into CRM_Accounts
Select Acct.AccountID,
   Acct.InternalName,
   QC.DescShort,
   AD.Addr1,
   AD.Addr2,
   AD.City,
   AD.State,
   AD.Zip,
   Sub.CodeID,
   Sub.Description,
   Peo.PersonID,
   Peo.FullName,
   PD1.FormattedNumber as 'Primary_Number',
   PD2.FormattedNumber as 'Secondary_Number'
From Accounts As Acct
INNER JOIN addressdetail AD ON Acct.AccountID = AD.AccountID
INNER JOIN CenterDetail CD ON Acct.CenterID = CD.CenterID
INNER JOIN People Peo ON Acct.LeaderID = Peo.PersonID
INNER JOIN IDViewOrgSubCenter SUB ON CD.OrgSubcenter = SUB.CodeID
INNER JOIN quickcodes QC ON Acct.AccountType = QC.CodeID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select AccountID, FormattedNumber, PrimaryPhone, row_number() over(partition by AccountID order by FormattedNumber) as rNum  
       From PhoneDetail where PrimaryPhone = 1) PD1
            ON Acct.accountid = PD1.AccountID and PD1.rNum = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select AccountID, FormattedNumber, PrimaryPhone, row_number() over(partition by AccountID order by FormattedNumber) as rNum  
       From PhoneDetail where PrimaryPhone <> 1) PD2
            ON Acct.AccountID = PD2.AccountID and PD2.rNum = 1
End
Go
```